# How integrate in my python code the google translator api correctly?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, google-translation-api

I'm actually doing a bot that forward messages from a channel to another channel.
It apply some changes like replace words, avoid voice or images ( as defined in the upper part of my code), and works perfectly this way.

But i'd like to add a functionally that translate the message AFTER the operations performed on it and forward the result like that :

"
[message forwarded after operations done on it]

---

[ message forwarded after operations done on it AND translated to French]

"

So there's the actual code, I imported google translate api, but don't understand where doing the operations, and how to concatenate without sending me those errors (cf. screenshot)

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.types import PeerChannel, MessageActionChatEditPhoto
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetBotCallbackAnswerRequest, DeleteMessagesRequest
from datetime import datetime

from googletrans import Translator

import time
import configparser
import re
import os
import logging
import sqlite3
import sys
import asyncio
       

def channel_group(config):
    channel_group_dic = {}
    channel_group_list = []

    for channel_group_from, channel_group_to in config.items('Settings'):
        firts_letter = channel_group_from[:1]
        if firts_letter.lower() == "g" or firts_letter.lower() == "c" or firts_letter.lower() == "b" or firts_letter.lower() == "u":
            channel_group_list.append(int(channel_group_from[1:]))
            channel_group_split = channel_group_to.split(";")
            temp_channel_group_list = []
            for channel_group in channel_group_split:
                first_letter_channel_group = channel_group[:1]
                if first_letter_channel_group.lower() == "g":
                    temp_channel_group_list.append(int("-"+channel_group[1:]))
                if first_letter_channel_group.lower() == "c":
                    temp_channel_group_list.append(int("-100"+channel_group[1:]))
            channel_group_dic[int(channel_group_from[1:])]=temp_channel_group_list
    return channel_group_list, channel_group_dic

        
def eval_list(string):
    string_list = None
    try:
        if isinstance(eval(string), list):
            string_list = eval(string)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error :",string)
    return string_list

def replace_list(string):
    replace_list = []
    for string in replace.split(";"):
        string_list = eval_list(string)
        if string_list:
            replace_list.append(string_list)
    return replace_list


def skip_list(string):
    skip_list = []
    string_list = eval_list(string)
    if string_list:
        skip_list = string_list
    return skip_list


def skip_message_image_list(string):
    channel_group_list = []
    for channel_group_from in string.split(";"):
        firts_letter = channel_group_from[:1]
        if firts_letter.lower() == "g" or firts_letter.lower() == "c" or firts_letter.lower() == "b" or firts_letter.lower() == "u":
            channel_group_list.append(int(channel_group_from[1:]))
    return channel_group_list
        

    
 
config = configparser.ConfigParser()

config.read('config.ini')


if not os.path.exists('config.ini'):
    print ("config.ini file not found")
    os.system("pause >nul")
    sys.exit()
    
api_id =  config.get('Settings', 'api_id')
api_hash = config.get('Settings', 'api_hash')
replace = config.get('Settings', 'replace')
allow_voice = config.getboolean('Settings', 'allow_voice')
allow_gif = config.getboolean('Settings', 'allow_gif')
skip = config.get('Settings', 'skip')
skip_message_image = config.get('Settings', 'skip_message_image')



skip_message_image_list = skip_message_image_list(skip_message_image)
replace_list = replace_list(replace)
skip_list = skip_list(skip)
channel_group_list_from, channel_group_dic_to = channel_group(config)

##print(channel_group_list_from)
##print(channel_group_dic_to)
##print(replace_list)

if not channel_group_list_from:
    sys.exit("Error")


client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)


@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channel_group_list_from,outgoing=False))
async def new_message_handler(event):

##        print(event)

        if event.is_channel:
            channel_group_id_from = event.message.peer_id.channel_id
        elif event.is_group:
            channel_group_id_from = event.message.peer_id.chat_id
        else:
            channel_group_id_from = event.message.peer_id.user_id
                   
        channel_group_message_id = event.message.id

        channel_group_message_text = event.message.message

        if event.photo:
            if channel_group_id_from in skip_message_image_list:
                print('Message Image Skipped ### ID:', channel_group_id_from)
                return
  
        for skip in skip_list:
            if skip in channel_group_message_text:
                print('Message Skipped:', channel_group_message_text," ### ID:", channel_group_id_from)
                return
                

        found = False
        for replace in replace_list:
            if replace[0] in channel_group_message_text:
                found = True
                event.message.message = channel_group_message_text.replace(replace[0],replace[1])

        channel_group_message = event.message
        
        message_text = event.raw_text
   **##   message_text_a_translate = event.raw_text
        
        
        
       message_translated = event.translator.translate( message_text, dest='fr', src='en')
       ## print('Message:', channel_group_message_text," ### ID:", channel_group_id_from)**

        if found:
          
            print('Message Edited in EN:', message_text)#affichage du message original apres traitement en anglais
            print('message Edited in FR :', message_translated)#affichage du message apres traitement et traduction en FRANCAIS
            
        if event.voice and not allow_voice:
            return

        if event.gif and not allow_gif:
            return
            
        for channel_group_to in channel_group_dic_to[channel_group_id_from]:            
            try:
                mirror_message = await client.send_message(channel_group_to, message=channel_group_message)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error:",e)        
                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.start()
    print("Waiting Messages...")
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

[Terminal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7OmL.png)

Comment: [ask]: "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question." Also I really suggest making a [mre], there's almost 200 lines of code here that probably don't all have to be.

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [example of googltrans](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#basic-usage), the sample usage of it is:

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()
trans_text = translator.translate('안녕하세요.')
print(trans_text)
 # output: Translated(src=ko, dest=en, text=Hello., pronunciation=None, extra_data="{'confiden...")
print(trans_text.text) # use .text to get the translated word
 # output: "Hello."
```

Based from your error you tried to use `event` to use the attributes of the `Translator()` class. Instead of using `event`, you should create an object using `Translator()` and use the object to perform translation.

Assuming `message_text` is a string. Your code should somewhat look like the one below.

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()
message_translated = translator.translate(message_text, dest='fr', src='en')
print(message_translated.text) # this should contain the translated text
```

Keep in mind that [googletrans](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is not the official Google Translation API so there will be limits applied if you are sending too much translation requests. I highly suggest to use the [official Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs) so you won't be encountering limitation issues moving forward. **See warning below from googletrans** documentation:

> - The maximum character limit on a single text is 15k.
> - Due to limitations of the web version of google translate, this API does not guarantee that the library would work properly at all times. (so
>   please use this library if you don’t care about stability.)
> - If you want to use a stable API, I highly recommend you to use [Google’s official translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs).
> - If you get HTTP 5xx error or errors like #6, it’s probably because Google has banned your client IP address.